# how to disble and enable swipe in pivot control of windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-8, pivot, swipe

I am using pivot control for swipe page in windows phone.

But in pivot i did not get any event left swipe is disable and right swipe is enable.

please help me how can i disable left swipe and how enable right swipe

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can read how to capture the gesture event [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff827740.aspx) , and read alls the gesture type on Windows phone [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.input.touch.gesturetype.aspx)

(swipe is a HorizontalDrag type on Windows Phone) .

Also, maybe when you are in your specific pivot page, you can abort the gesture event.

You have also [this website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/design/hh202911%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) for more informations...

Comment: :thanks for replay and  i am in specific page at that time i already abort gesture event but pivot swipe is runnig?

Comment: :my concept is when i swipe in left to right at that time some data is fill in my graph and when i swipe right to left at that time some data is fill in my graph....now what i want?, when some specific point i want to stop right to left swipe.but do not stop left to right swipe

Comment: :i already handle this think through pivit.Islocked event but it have one problem.  how to enavle this event in right to left swipe?