# Detection of swipe direction in pivot

Tags: windows-phone-8, pivot

I work in windows phone 8 and I have two pivot item in a Pivot control.
How to detect if i swiped to the right or to the left ?

Comment: Check [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20297442/2982225) and [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18529734/2982225)

Comment: I've removed a tag from question's title - please note than in most cases questions [shouldn't include tag in their title.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Step1:Add Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit in your solution

Step2:Add Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit reference in xaml like this:

```
xmlns:tolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
```

Step3:Create gesture listener flick event like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <tolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
            <tolkit:GestureListener Flick="GestureListener_Flick"></tolkit:GestureListener>
        </tolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
        <!--Pivot Control-->
        <controls:Pivot Title="MY APPLICATION">
            <!--Pivot item one-->
            <controls:PivotItem Header="item1">
                <Grid/>
            </controls:PivotItem>

            <!--Pivot item two-->
            <controls:PivotItem Header="item2">
                <Grid/>
            </controls:PivotItem>
        </controls:Pivot>
    </Grid>
```

Step 4:In your cs page add this code:

```
 private void GestureListener_Flick(object sender, FlickGestureEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Direction.ToString() == "Horizontal") //Left or right
            {
                if (e.HorizontalVelocity > 0) //Right
                {

                }
                else //Left
                {

                }
            }
        }
```

[you could download toolkit from here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=9D8B857AF743EE37!240&authkey=!AFg-7dKQZVEzmOU&ithint=file,.dll)

Comment: this code is working for me ,i have used in my solution, if you find any problem tell me for that

Comment: Thank you great expalanation

Answer (score 1):

For simple case (if you have more that 2 pivot items) you can use `SelectionChanged` event of your Pivot - provide variable in which you will save last SelectedIndex and after the change check if it was right or left:

```
myPivot.SelectionChanged+=myPivot_SelectionChanged; // in your MainPage()

private int lastSelected = 0;

private void myPivot_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   if ((lastSelected + 1 == myPivot.SelectedIndex) || 
       (myPivot.SelectedIndex == 0 && lastSelected == myPivot.Items.Count - 1))
   {
     // moved right
   }
   else 
   {  
     // moved left 
   }

   lastSelected = myPivot.SelectedIndex;
}
```

For simple cases it should work, for more complicated you can use `TouchPanel` or other solutions.

Comment: I think that your code will not work on my example because I use two pivot item and when I swype to the right or to the left lastSelected and selectedindex will have the same values

Comment: if i move left SelectedIndex is also (1) (because I have only 2 items) so i will not distinguish the direction. But it's a good solution in case there are three or more items. I think that I have to use toolkits in this case. Thank you for your help

Comment: @user3471718 I must say that you are right - with two items, basing only on their numbers it is imposiible to tell if the movement was right or left.

Comment: It is possible

You can use something like this to determine:

var Selection = e.AddedItems[0]; // Selection
var LastSelection = e.RemovedItems[0] // Last Selection

and by casting the above as (PivotItem)
to compute the difference.

Comment: @NavikGoswami When you have only two items, then no matter in which direction you swipe, you will have the same RemovedItem - so it's still not possible to determine the direction.

Comment: I don't think it'd matter...You could get -1 or 1 as the difference and that would be sufficient to deduce the direction.

Comment: @NavikGoswami When you have Added/RemovedItem you can have its index for example - these are 0 and 1 - how can you get -1 or +1 when moving left/right? Have you got an idea?

Comment: Just posted my answer. Please have a look.

Comment: @NavikGoswami Your solution suffers the same problem - it won't work with two items. Have you tried it with only two items?

Comment: @NavikGoswami Yes, and it suffers the problem I've described - when you are on the second item, no matter if you swipe left/right, your index changes from 1 to 0 - you always get `// moved right`.

Comment: Yeah, I didnt check both the cases...in a hurry. You're right.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `Items.Count`, you could the EventArgs paramater `e` to determine the last Index within the Pivot Items Collection and the selected index by using the following:

```
        private void pivot_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Casting e.AddedItems and e.RemovedItems to the PivotItem type to get 
        // the Selected Pivot and the Last Selected Pivot

        var selectedPivot = (PivotItem) e.AddedItems[0];
        var lastPivot = (PivotItem) e.RemovedItems[0];

        // Getting indices using the ItemCollection of the pivot

        int selectedIndex = pivot.Items.IndexOf(selectedPivot);
        int previousIndex = pivot.Items.IndexOf(lastPivot);

        if (selectedIndex < previousIndex)
        {
            // user swiped to the right
        }
        else
        {
            // user swiped to the left
        }

    }
```

This should help you even if you have only two pivots.

Answer (score 0):

Nice work by all, but what will we do when we click on a button to navigate forward and backword the PivotItems.

So just put the following code in Two Buttons i.e. Forward and Backward.
You can easily achieve this via setting the Pivot.SelectedIndex

for forward

```
    if(pivotName.SelectedIndex < (pivotName.Items.Count - 1))
    pivotName.SelectedIndex++;
    else
    pivotName.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

for backward

```
    if(pivotName.S electedIndex > 0)
    pivotName.SelectedIndex--;
    else
    pivotName.SelectedIndex = pivotName.Items.Count - 1;
```